# Select last 3 children based on the number of children

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, siblings

I'm in a situation where the number of elements shown is variable, and I need solution which I'm not able to achieve, I even doubt if it's possible only with CSS.

I want to make a selection on the last four items only when the total items are 7. the my current CSS gives right result for 7 items but not for an another amount.

how can I combine that so that it looks for `nth-last-child(7)` and `flex-item:nth-child(n+5)`?

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-item:first-child:nth-last-child(7),
.flex-item:first-child:nth-last-child(7)~.flex-item:nth-child(-n+4) {
  flex-basis: 23%;
}

.flex-item:nth-last-child(7)~.flex-item:nth-child(n+5) {
  flex-basis: 31%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
  <li class="flex-item">7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You will need to use JavaScript to apply the selector you want only when it detects 7 elements.

Comment: To clarify - you need to select the last 4 items when there are 5 or more items right?

Comment: @Huangism The question says OP wants to select the last three items when there are exactly 7 items, but don't select them when there are any more or any less.

Comment: Oh the description says four, must of been a typo

Comment: @TylerH are you sure about the requirements? it seems OP already has that ability with `.flex-item:first-child:nth-last-child(7)` I left an answer but I mean the answer is in the question already if that's what OP wants

Comment: @Huangism based off of "*I want to make a selection on the last four items only when the total items are 7*", yes. It's possible OP meant to ask something else, but that's what they said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

`.flex-item:first-child:nth-last-child(7)`

targets the first child when there are only 7 items so that

`.flex-item:first-child:nth-last-child(7)~.flex-item:nth-child(n+5)`

is only triggered when there are 7 items

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-item:first-child:nth-last-child(7),
.flex-item:first-child:nth-last-child(7)~.flex-item:nth-child(-n+4) {
  flex-basis: 23%;
}

.flex-item:first-child:nth-last-child(7)~.flex-item:nth-child(n+5) {
  flex-basis: 31%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item first">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
  <li class="flex-item">7</li>
</ul>
<br/><br/>
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item first">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
  <li class="flex-item">7</li>
  <li class="flex-item">8</li>
  <li class="flex-item">9</li>
  <li class="flex-item">10</li>
</ul>
<br/><br/>
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item first">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
</ul>
```